# Taylor Series Power Function in R

Tags: r, epidemiology, taylor-series, disease

I'm trying to recreate a compartmental model from Yu et al (2017). In this model there is a expanded taylor series power function that is used that I am not understanding how to code.
[image: powerfunction]
where W(t) = 0, K = 1350, and N = 0. W(t) will increase in number as it is recent mortality based on other equations.

[image]

The model above is the kind I am trying to create. where the W compartment is the recent mortality (which is where W(t) comes form). I am aware of how to code the other compartments but the effect B(W(t);k;N) has on S is where I am struggling.

B(W(t);k;N) is a behavioural function: "This function models peoples decrease in exposure to infectious individuals in response to reported influenza mortality"

I was looking into the taylor function and but I'm not understanding how to use it. The basic model outline I have is this:

```
sir.model.closed <- function (t, x, params) { #here we begin a function with three arguments
  S <- x[1] #create local variable S, the first element of x
  I <- x[2] #create local variable I
  R <- x[3] #create local variable R
  D <- x[4] #create a local variable for D
  W <- x[5] #create a local variable for W
  V <- x[6] #create a local variable for V
  with( #we can simplify code using "with"
    as.list(params), #this argument to "with" lets us use the variable names
    { #the system of rate equations
      dS <-  
      dI <- 
      dR <- 
      dD <-
      dW <-
      dV <- 
      dx <- c(dS,dI,dR,dD,dW,dV) #combine results into a single vector dx
      list(dx) #return result as a list
    }
  )
}
```

Any guidance in this area would be appreciated.

Yu D, Lin Q, Chiu AP, He D (2017) Effects of reactive social distancing on the 1918 influenza pandemic. PLoS ONE 12(7): e0180545. https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0180545